# Running docker service in a docker-compose at different time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose which looks like following i want to run service httpd at first and after some time i want to run tomcat is it possible to do that without using two docker-compose and only using the given docker compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  tomcat:
    expose:
      - "8009"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    image: 192.168.56.1:5000/tomcat
  httpd:
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
    ports:
      - 80:80
    image: 192.168.56.1:5000/apache
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want both services starting up together?

Comment: Yes, I have to start the second docker only when neccessary. Also the reason i am trying this is because, when run  toghether the httpd is communicating with the tomcat properly but when i am putting them in different docker-compose they are not communicating, even though i put them on same network, so now i am going for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a dependency between the services by using the `depends_on` key eg.

```yaml
services:
  tomcat:
    ...
    depends_on:
    - httpd
  httpd:
    ...
```

Comment: So how will that work? like when i run docker compose will it run httpd first , how will i start tomcat later?

Comment: Docker compose will ensure that the dependents of a services are started before starting that particular service. But, note that it will not wait for the application to come up and become healthy.